# What is the difference between a struct of the same datatype and an array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, padding

If I had a struct consisting only of short unsigned integers, that would be stored in contiguous memory locations of the same size; the same also applies if I have an array of short unsigned integers. How would they be any different? Is it how they are accessed? I am aware that an array is accessed by using a pointer to reference the starting value of the array while an array operator sets an offset from that memory location, does the same apply to structs or are structs accessed by using the memory location for each piece of data?

Comment: The difference is you don't control the padding that may/may not be added to the struct (without giving certain preprocessor instructions). The array is just *x-number* of `shorts`, the `struct` is that plus any padding added.

Comment: A `struct` can be passed/returned from a function.  An array cannot.

Comment: So assuming I wanted to pass from a function a series of contiguous memory locations without padding, what would I have to do?

Comment: Pass a structure with an array in it.

Comment: The usual way to deal with arrays is via a pointer to the element type. For example a function that manipulates an array of `unsigned short` would receive an argument of type `unsigned short*`, with added information (probably another argument) indicating how many elements are in the array.

Answer (score 2):

No, they need not be the same and most likely, they are not.

In case of structure members, there can be padding between the members. So, it is not guaranteed that consecutive members will reside in contiguous memory. In this case, based on implementation, pointer arithmetic using the address of the first element may or may not <del>work</del> be valid.

Quoting relevant parts of `C11` standard, chapter §6.7.2.1/p15, Structure and union specifiers,

> [..] There may be unnamed
>   padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

and

chapter §6.5.3.4, `sizeof` operator,

> [...] When
>   applied to an operand that has structure or union type, the result is the total number of
>   bytes in such an object, including internal and trailing padding.

In case of an array, however, all members are guaranteed to reside in contiguous memory and pointer arithmetic is deterministic.

Comment: "*No, they need not be the same*" -- agreed "*and most likely, they are not*" -- Most likely they *are*.  A structure whose members are all the same type will very likely allocate them contiguously. But there might be padding at the end, if the compiler decides to impose stricter alignment on the structure than on its members.